# How to find $f(x)$ in this question and solve the integral as $x$ is defined in a range and also varies with value of $n$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals

> If $f(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ for $\frac{1}{2^n}<x\le\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, $x\in [0,1]$, $n\in \Bbb N$ and $f(0)=0$. Find the value of $\int_0^1f(x)dx$.

My attempt:
The main confusion is that as $f(x)$ only depends on n (i.e, constant with $x$), so in this integral I directly plugged the $f(x)$ and then got it as $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, but this approach is completely wrong according to the given solution. I cannot understand that once when they have mentioned $x$$\in$[0,1] then we have to we vary 'n' according to the previous relation as n=0 to n=$\infty$, or any alternate approach? Because they have used the concept of areas and wrote the integral in terms of n but converting integral to limit sum problem(main confusion). Any alternate approach would be really helpful and also to spot the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is assuming that f(x) is a constant and doesn't change with x. In reality, this function is a piecewise function. Let us try putting in some values.
$$f(1)=\frac{1}{2^0}; \frac{1}{2}<1\leq \frac{1}{2^0}$$
$$f(\frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{4}< \frac{1}{2}\leq \frac{1}{2}$$
$$f(\frac{1}{3})=\frac{1}{2}; \frac{1}{4}< \frac{1}{3} \leq \frac{1}{2}$$
$$f(\frac{1}{4})=\frac{1}{4}; \frac{1}{8}< \frac{1}{4} \leq \frac{1}{4}$$
and so on.
You can probably see that it is kind of like a ceiling function but it pushes the number up to the closest negative power of 2.
Like any piecewise function this can be evaluated by splitting the integral into smaller bits.
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx = \int_\frac{1}{2}^1dx + \int_\frac{1}{4}^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}dx + \int_\frac{1}{8}^\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4}dx ...$$
$$=[x]_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 + \frac{1}{2}[x]_{\frac{1}{4}}^{\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{4}[x]_{\frac{1}{8}}^{\frac{1}{4}}...$$
$$=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{32} + ...$$
Which is a simple infinite Geometric Progression. So I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: yes, now clearly understood the concept and the interlinking of the quesion. Thank you very much :)